# Can I use a bus ticket straight away after rolling a double?

Tags: monopoly-mega-edition

I would like to know: if a player rolls doubles twice then lands on the birthday gift and collects a bus ticket, can that player use their bus ticket immediately or do they have to roll again because they rolled doubles?

Answer (score 1):

From the rules [here](https://winning-moves.com/images/megamonopolyrules.pdf)

> If doubles entitle you to roll again, you may use a Bus Ticket in
> place of rolling the dice.

The rules for birthday gift say

> BIRTHDAY GIFT If you land here collect $100 from the Bank, or draw a
> Bus Ticket for use on a later turn. Your choice.

So the question is is rolling again due to a double is the same turn or a new turn. The rules state the following.

> After you have completed your play, the turn passes to the left.

So reading that it sounds like rolling again it part of the same 'turn' or 'play' and not a new and separate turn.  So if a bus ticket is taken for 'use on a later turn' then they would not get to use it immediately.

However this terminology is contradicted in rules for getting out of jail by rolling a double.

> Even though you rolled doubles, you do not take another turn.

So it seems the rules are confused on what is 'a turn' and if that differs from 'rolling again'

Personally I would let them as that seems to make more sense thematically that you can use a ticket straight away, maybe one to discuss as a house rule before you start as there is an argument in the rules for both.